# Count multiple distinct values - Linq

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I have a list of **points** (each point has `id,x,y,z` properties).

I would like to get the **total distinct values** of properties `x,y,z`

I am doing:

```
var points = new List<MyPoint>
{
    new MyPoint {Id = 0, X = 97.5, Y = 92.5, Z = -16.6666660308838},
    new MyPoint {Id = 1, X = 292.5, Y = 92.5, Z = -16.6666660308838},
    new MyPoint {Id = 2, X = 97.5, Y = 277.5, Z = -16.6666660308838},
    new MyPoint {Id = 3, X = 292.5, Y = 277.5, Z = -16.6666660308838},
    new MyPoint {Id = 4, X = 97.5, Y = 462.5, Z = -16.6666660308838},
    new MyPoint {Id = 5, X = 292.5, Y = 462.5, Z = -16.6666660308838},
    new MyPoint {Id = 6, X = 97.5, Y = 92.5, Z = -49.9999980926514},
    new MyPoint {Id = 7, X = 292.5, Y = 92.5, Z = -49.9999980926514},
    new MyPoint {Id = 8, X = 97.5, Y = 277.5, Z = -49.9999980926514},
    new MyPoint {Id = 9, X = 292.5, Y = 277.5, Z = -49.9999980926514},
    new MyPoint {Id = 10, X = 97.5, Y = 462.5, Z = -49.9999980926514},
    new MyPoint {Id = 11, X = 292.5, Y = 462.5, Z = -49.9999980926514},
    new MyPoint {Id = 12, X = 97.5, Y = 92.5, Z = -83.3333320617676},
    new MyPoint {Id = 13, X = 292.5, Y = 92.5, Z = -83.3333320617676},
    new MyPoint {Id = 14, X = 97.5, Y = 277.5, Z = -83.3333320617676},
    new MyPoint {Id = 15, X = 292.5, Y = 277.5, Z = -83.3333320617676},
    new MyPoint {Id = 16, X = 97.5, Y = 462.5, Z = -83.3333320617676},
    new MyPoint {Id = 17, X = 292.5, Y = 462.5, Z = -83.3333320617676}
};
var result =
    points
    .GroupBy(l => l.Id)
    .Select(g => new
    {
        sizeX = g.Select(l => l.X).Distinct().Count(),
        sizeY = g.Select(l => l.Y).Distinct().Count(),
        sizeZ = g.Select(l => l.Z).Distinct().Count()
    });
```

I am getting this:

[image]

How can I fix this so I get

```
X ->2
Y ->3
Z ->3
```

?

Comment: What do you think `GroupBy(l => l.Id)` does?

Comment: Well, so I need to group by other property, but well, as I need to count disctinct X,Y,Z how to do it? Or As I understand to group by all three properties?

Comment: You can group via anonymous object. `GroupBy(l => new { l.sizeX, l.sizeY, l.sizeZ })`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is following what you need?

```
var result = new
{
    sizeX = points.Select(l => l.X).Distinct().Count(),
    sizeY = points.Select(l => l.Y).Distinct().Count(),
    sizeZ = points.Select(l => l.Z).Distinct().Count()
};
```

Comment: @cMinor not sure if you have heard about "premature optimization is the root of all evil", but I suggest trying it and measure the speed for yourself. LINQ solutions are usually few times slower than non-LINQ solutions, but they are still more than fast enough in most cases.

Comment: I'd suggest that you delete everything from the word **Edit** and onward.

Answer (score 3):

You can either do:

```
    HashSet<double> xes = new HashSet<double>();
    HashSet<double> yes = new HashSet<double>();
    HashSet<double> zes = new HashSet<double>();

    foreach (MyPoint pt in list)
    {
      xes.Add(pt.X);
      yes.Add(pt.Y);
      zes.Add(pt.Z);
    }
```

and then call `Count` on the hash sets:

```
int countX = xes.Count; etc...
```

or

```
    HashSet<double> xes = new HashSet<double>();
    HashSet<double> yes = new HashSet<double>();
    HashSet<double> zes = new HashSet<double>();

    list.Aggregate((xes, yes, zes), (acc, pt) =>
    {
      acc.xes.Add(pt.X);
      acc.yes.Add(pt.Y);
      acc.zes.Add(pt.Z);
      return acc;
    });
```

and then call `Count` on the hash sets:

```
int countX = xes.Count; etc...
```

Comment: I knew you were joking, but still quickly googled it =D